Ubuntu Upgrade Issues
I have a Google VM Instance originally created with Linux Ubuntu ver 18.04.  I installed LAMP stack (Apache2, MySQL, PHP) and Postfix as a Send-Only SMTP Server.  I had a website set up which I have had for several years.  I just upgraded Ubuntu to ver 24.04.  I did all the update/upgrades prior to running the Ubuntu upgrade (sudo do-release-upgrade).  Everything seemed normal with the upgrade and when it finished I rebooted.
To accomplish the update, I ran the following commands in order from the terminal CLI:
sudo apt update,
sudo apt upgrade,
sudo do-release-upgrade
After I rebooted I was unable to SSH connect to the instance.  I was finally able to connect using the Cloud Shell on the VM Instances page.  I found that not only had Ubuntu been updated to version 24.04, but MySQL, PHP, and I assume Apache had been updated also.  My databases were gone and all my html files were gone.
The html files were located in the /var/www/html/ directory.
The MySQL database was located in the /var/lib/mysql directory.
Luckily, I had all of those backed up including some of the configuration files.  My main purpose for the VM Instance was a learning platform and was not that important.  I would appreciate it if someone could explain possibly what happened.  I was under the assumption that when the OS was updated, none of the user files were altered or removed.
Is this normal when you update Ubuntu on a Linux machine?
Also, I noticed that the original storage space on the VM was 20 gb and there was about 11 gb of unused space.  After the update, the storage space had increased to 114 gb and 59 gb used.  Did the newer version of Ubuntu require six times the space of the original version?
I realize this is an Ubuntu forum and this question may not be relavant, but would it make more sense to add my databases, html files and re-configure everything or delete the original updated instance, create a new instance and start all over?

Hmmm. Running sudo do-release-upgrade on an Ubuntu 18.04 system should have brought you to 20.04, not to 24.04. Your experience seems highly unusual. Unless a skilled tester has also experienced this unusual behavior, your questions may not be answerable. Except, of course, for your final question: Delete the original instance and start over.
